can time series models have random effects?
I have seen this link over here where it shows that time series models can be made to handle mixed effects/hierarchical structures: https://otexts.com/fpp2/hts.html
I am wondering if this is true for all types of all types of time series models?
For example, consider a VAR model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) where each variable depends on previous versions of itself and the other variables:

$$X_t = a_{10} + a_{11}X_{t-1} + a_{12}Y_{t-1} + a_{13}Z_{t-1} +  \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = a_{20} + a_{21}X_{t-1} + a_{22}Y_{t-1} + a_{23}Z_{t-1} +  \epsilon_{2t}$$
$$Z_t = a_{30} + a_{31}X_{t-1} + a_{32}Y_{t-1} + a_{33}Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{3t}$$
$$\mathbf{w}_t = \begin{pmatrix} X_t \\ Y_t \\ Z_t \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{a}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} a_{10} \\ a_{20} \\ a_{30} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{\epsilon}_t = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_{1t} \\ \epsilon_{2t} \\ \epsilon_{3t} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{w}_t = \mathbf{a}_0 + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}_{t-1} + \mathbf{\epsilon}_t$$

Is it possible to introduce random effects into this model?
I tried to do this myself:

$$X_{tj} = (a_{10} + u_{1j}) + a_{11}X_{t-1,j} + a_{12}Y_{t-1,j} + a_{13}Z_{t-1,j} + \epsilon_{1tj}$$
$$Y_{tj} = (a_{20} + u_{2j}) + a_{21}X_{t-1,j} + a_{22}Y_{t-1,j} + a_{23}Z_{t-1,j} + \epsilon_{2tj}$$
$$Z_{tj} = (a_{30} + u_{3j}) + a_{31}X_{t-1,j} + a_{32}Y_{t-1,j} + a_{33}Z_{t-1,j} + \epsilon_{3tj}$$
$$\mathbf{w}_{tj} = \begin{pmatrix} X_{tj} \\ Y_{tj} \\ Z_{tj} \end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{a}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} a_{10} \\ a_{20}  \\ a_{30} \end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{u}_j = \begin{pmatrix} u_{1j} \\ u_{2j} \\ u_{3j} \end{pmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{\epsilon}_{tj} =  \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_{1tj} \\ \epsilon_{2tj} \\ \epsilon_{3tj} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{w}_{tj} = \mathbf{a}_0 + \mathbf{u}_j + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}_{t-1,j} + \mathbf{\epsilon}_{tj}$$
$$\mathbf{u}_j \sim N(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_u)$$
$$\mathbf{\epsilon}_{tj} \sim N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma}_\epsilon)$$

Is this statistically correct?

Hi: In the VAR setting, fixed effects are complex enough because you've got the whole lack of identifiability issue. (see structural var versus reduced form var ). I have no idea how the issues in the fixed effect case get untangled when one moves to random effects ? Definitely it's dangerous territory. Could you tell me where to find a good explanation of random effects versus fixed effects because the latter always confused me but luckily I've never needed them. Thanks.

This doesn't get into all of the details but it does a pretty good job with the identifiability issues in just the VAR case with fixed effects.  https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/svarslides.pdf

hi! can you please explain why adding random effects to a VAR model can introduce identifiability problems?

Basically, I have data for multiple provinces in the same country, i.e clustered data. I wanted to use a random effects approach to capture this

I was not clear. There are already identifiability problems in a VAR because the covariance matrix is not identified. See the document for why this is the case. But what I meant was, if you try adding random effects ( which are beyond my current understanding. I remember them being in one of my courses but I never TRULY understood them ), then that makes it more complicated. But I don't know what it does to the identifiability issues that are already present without them !!!!!! If you understand that document, then maybe you'll understand what the ramifications are when adding random effects.

I will look into the svar model as well

yes, the svar is one approach for dealing with the identifiability issue. I don't know what your background is but enders covers the identifiability issue in a clear, introductory way. There's a also a textbook on structural var models ( whose name escapes me ) but I don't know the level of details you want to get into. I hope this helped some and good luck.

Here's a thread the explains the restrictions in a concise and clear manner. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/58980/svar-proof-of-the-k2-k-2-restrictions-and-identifiability
