How to tell if a model is identifiable?
I am trying to find some references which explain how do we know that a statistical model is identifiable. My current understanding of identifiability is when only a single set of solutions exist for the parameter estimates.
I am just interested in knowing: If we look at a model, is there some statistical test or condition we can check to instantly determine if the model is identifiable or not? Or do we we have to manually analyze the model and determine if it is identifiable or not?
I found a specific example here for linear regression: Identifiability of the linear regression model: necessary and sufficient condition
But does anything exist in general?

This question is closely related to, but not (IMO) a duplicate of How do we Deal with Identifiability Problems in Statistics? That question has some good answers (one of which has been modified to answer this question by @camille-gontier).

This is a very big field: e.g.

Cole, Diana. 2020. Parameter Redundancy and Identifiability. 1st edition. Boca Raton London New York, NY: Chapman and Hall/CRC
or this PubMed search

In other words, it's very hard to do in general. There is a lot of work on identifiability of parameters of dynamical systems (e.g. models in pharmacology, epidemiology, oncology, epidemiology, systems biology, economics, ...) (If you're starting to dig into this literature you might want to start with the economics literature, which focuses on the identifiability of linear dynamical systems — easier than starting with the nonlinear systems typical of the other fields mentioned ...)
Remien, Christopher H., Mariah J. Eckwright, and Benjamin J. Ridenhour. 2021. “Structural Identifiability of the Generalized Lotka-Volterra Model for Microbiome Studies.” Royal Society Open Science 8 (7): 201378. https://doi.org/10.1098/rsos.201378.
Wieland, Franz-Georg, Adrian L. Hauber, Marcus Rosenblatt, Christian Tönsing, and Jens Timmer. 2021. “On Structural and Practical Identifiability.” Current Opinion in Systems Biology 25 (March):60–69. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.coisb.2021.03.005.

Ah ok, so it looks like there is no quick and easy way to tell if a model is identifiable. Actually, this question that I asked originates from the discussion here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/659202/can-time-series-models-have-random-effects .... I didn't know that introducing random effects into time series models can create identifiability problems

Yes, your time series question is exactly the case of a linear dynamical system that I mentioned in my answer ...

There may be some more easily applicable rules in the specific case of linear dynamical systems, but I don't know the field that well and didn't want to spend the time digging through to find out.  Someone more knowledgeable might reply with a more precise (but limited) answer ...

It's a big field and also a fairly old one. In Econometrics it is referred to as the parameter identification problem and in philosophy of science it is called the underdetermination problem. Ironically both were identified at roughly the same time (the 1910s) and made their way to english at the same time (~1950s).

There are two types of (non)-identifiabilities:

Structural identifiability. This refers to an intrinsic property of a model, for which different combinations of its parameters would yield exactly the same output. For instance, if the relation between the input $x$ and the output $y$ is $y=(A+B)x$ (with free parameters $A$ and $B$), then the model is said to be structurally non-identifiable. Different criteria exist to detect it, eg

Massonis, G., & Villaverde, A. F. (2020). Finding and breaking Lie symmetries: implications for structural identifiability and observability in biological modelling. Symmetry, 12(3), 469.

Practical identifiability. This refers to a property of your experimental setting, in which the parameters of an otherwise structurally identifiable model cannot be accurately determined due to observations being scarce and/or noisy, for instance. Different criteria exist to quantify it, eg

Gontier, C., & Pfister, J. P. (2020). Identifiability of a binomial synapse. Frontiers in computational neuroscience, 14, 558477.
Raue, Andreas, et al. "Structural and practical identifiability analysis of partially observed dynamical models by exploiting the profile likelihood." Bioinformatics 25.15 (2009): 1923-1929.
(paraphrased from a previous answer).
